# Foreman start not launching redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, fedora, foreman

We are two people working on a Rails app running with foreman. 
The app successfully launches on one computer but not the other. The other computer also has another independent project running successfully with foreman (but not running in the same time).

On computer 1:
- `foreman start`
- launches redis, sidekiq, server is running

On computer 2: 
- `foreman start`

```
17:20:02 web.1     | started with pid 14758
17:20:02 webpack.1 | started with pid 14759
17:20:02 redis.1   | started with pid 14760
17:20:02 sidekiq.1 | started with pid 14761
17:20:02 redis.1   | 14760:C 27 Jul 2019 17:20:02.339 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
17:20:02 redis.1   | 14760:C 27 Jul 2019 17:20:02.339 # Redis version=5.0.4, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=14760, just started
17:20:02 redis.1   | 14760:C 27 Jul 2019 17:20:02.339 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
17:20:02 redis.1   | 14760:M 27 Jul 2019 17:20:02.340 # You requested maxclients of 10000 requiring at least 10032 max file descriptors.
17:20:02 redis.1   | 14760:M 27 Jul 2019 17:20:02.340 # Server can't set maximum open files to 10032 because of OS error: Operation not permitted.
17:20:02 redis.1   | 14760:M 27 Jul 2019 17:20:02.340 # Current maximum open files is 4096. maxclients has been reduced to 4064 to compensate for low ulimit. If you need higher maxclients increase 'ulimit -n'.
17:20:02 redis.1   | 14760:M 27 Jul 2019 17:20:02.341 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
17:20:02 redis.1   | 14760:M 27 Jul 2019 17:20:02.341 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
17:20:02 redis.1   | 14760:M 27 Jul 2019 17:20:02.341 # Server initialized
17:20:02 redis.1   | 14760:M 27 Jul 2019 17:20:02.341 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
17:20:02 redis.1   | 14760:M 27 Jul 2019 17:20:02.341 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
17:20:02 redis.1   | 14760:M 27 Jul 2019 17:20:02.341 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
17:20:02 redis.1   | 14760:M 27 Jul 2019 17:20:02.341 * Ready to accept connections
17:20:02 webpack.1 | /home/DupuisRodolphe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/webpacker-3.6.0/lib/webpacker/dev_server_runner.rb:55:in `exec': No such file or directory - /home/DupuisRodolphe/JavaScript/rails/gestion-locative-saas/node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server (Errno::ENOENT)
17:20:02 webpack.1 |    from /home/DupuisRodolphe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/webpacker-3.6.0/lib/webpacker/dev_server_runner.rb:55:in `block in execute_cmd'
17:20:02 webpack.1 |    from /home/DupuisRodolphe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/webpacker-3.6.0/lib/webpacker/dev_server_runner.rb:54:in `chdir'
17:20:02 webpack.1 |    from /home/DupuisRodolphe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/webpacker-3.6.0/lib/webpacker/dev_server_runner.rb:54:in `execute_cmd'
17:20:02 webpack.1 |    from /home/DupuisRodolphe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/webpacker-3.6.0/lib/webpacker/dev_server_runner.rb:12:in `run'
17:20:02 webpack.1 |    from /home/DupuisRodolphe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/webpacker-3.6.0/lib/webpacker/runner.rb:6:in `run'
17:20:02 webpack.1 |    from ./bin/webpack-dev-server:15:in `<main>'
17:20:03 webpack.1 | exited with code 1
17:20:03 system    | sending SIGTERM to all processes
17:20:03 redis.1   | 14760:signal-handler (1564240803) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
17:20:03 redis.1   | 14760:M 27 Jul 2019 17:20:03.443 # User requested shutdown...
17:20:03 redis.1   | 14760:M 27 Jul 2019 17:20:03.443 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
17:20:03 redis.1   | 14760:M 27 Jul 2019 17:20:03.455 * DB saved on disk
17:20:03 redis.1   | 14760:M 27 Jul 2019 17:20:03.455 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
17:20:03 web.1     | terminated by SIGTERM
17:20:03 redis.1   | exited with code 0
17:20:03 sidekiq.1 | terminated by SIGTERM
```

Computer 2 tried to connect redis in the background with `redis-server` and running `foreman start -m all=1,redis=0` (otherwise: `bind: Address already in use`) but it not successful.

`Procfile.dev` :

```
web:     rails server
webpack: ./bin/webpack-dev-server --watch --colors --progress
redis:   redis-server
sidekiq: bundle exec sidekiq -q *something*
```

We have no clue on what to do now.

Comment: Is redis being hosted locally or are you using redis as a service

Comment: It is also possible that on computer 2, redis is already running in the background and hence the port is already bound. run `ps -ef | grep redis` to find out if redis is running before running foreman start

Comment: @MoizMansur as i said in my post, there is an other project on computer that runs perfectly when we do `redis-server` and then `foreman start`

Comment: Are you sure redis is the problem? If I see this line: `17:20:02 webpack.1 | /home/DupuisRodolphe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/webpacker-3.6.0/lib/webpacker/dev_server_runner.rb:55:in 'exec': No such file or directory - /home/DupuisRodolphe/JavaScript/rails/gestion-locative-saas/node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server (Errno::ENOENT)` after that error it stops everything.